# How can I run Composer from source and/or allow step-through debugging with PhpStorm?

Tags: php, composer-php, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying to troubleshoot a Composer command failure, and I'd like to step-through Composer's code so that I can inspect the program state at the time of failure.

Is it possible to run Composer from source, so that PhpStorm can more easily use Xdebug's step through debugging tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone source code from repository and use it directly by [`bin/composer`](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/bin/composer):

```
git clone https://github.com/composer/composer.git composer-src
cd composer-src
composer install
bin/composer --version
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `composer.phar` to your project, and run that copy, not the global `composer` instance.

If you do that, PhpStorm includes support for working wit an debugging Phar files directly, as described here:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/05/working-with-phar-packages-in-phpstorm/ ([web archive link](http://web.archive.org/web/20160924201117/https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/05/working-with-phar-packages-in-phpstorm/))

Or of course, you could simply download/clone the whole composer code inside your project, and use that. The source code includes a `composer` executable on `bin/composer` which you could execute directly. You'd need to do a full `composer install` as well to get the project's dependencies (which are already included in the phar file).

If you are running composer remotely (e.g. within a docker container), and using a global composer installation within your container (e.g. outside your project directory); when you start the debug session PhpStorm would complain about not being able to map the code.

In that case you could simply use path mappings under "Language and Frameworks -> PHP -> Server" to map the remote composer instance to a host installation.

Comment: I've tried debugging composer.phar, and while the debugger enters properly, it's more or less illegible for step-through purposes.

Comment: That's why I also mentioned you could clone and install the project.